# Empty bool clause causing zero results being returned in elasticsearch

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I wrote an API in ruby that helps clients build the elasticsearch query dsl.
The query that is built up contains an empty bool as shown below which is causing problems. With the bool being empty like that, it's causing 0 results to be returned. If I remove the bool I get the expected result. **How can I turn this into a match_all without removing that bool?** I need to leave the bool there until the next release where I can remove it. If I add a must in the bool by default with a match_all in there, I feel it may have unexpected results.

**Elastic version: 1.0.1**

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {} <--- Causing problems
            },
            "filter": {
                "query": {
                    "query_string": {
                        "fields": [
                            [
                                "name_field",
                                "message_field"
                            ]
                        ],
                        "query": "Halo AND Yaylo"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "interactions": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What version of ES is this?

Comment: Thanks, I've added that detail to the question. The version is: `1.0.1`.

Comment: Then this is your answer: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7240

Comment: Okay, that's just the problem. What about the solution? Can't change versions of elastic in production at this stage.

Comment: No, that's also the solution. The change went into 1.4, 2.0 and 1.3.3. And 1.0.1 is a very very old version of Elasticsearch. At this point, with 1.7.1 as the latest, it's light years ahead.

Comment: I guess my question is, can I add a must clause inside the bool with a match_all so that the query doesn't crash? would that cause problems when clients add **Real** musts to the bool?

Comment: I think it should be ok.

Comment: Actually, it does have an impact. It changes the scoring...

Comment: any ideas of how I can neutralize the scoring then?

Comment: Also, this statement for `bool` will be affected as well: `"By default, none of the should clauses are required to match, with one exception: if there are no must clauses, then at least one should clause must match."` So, in case your real musts are 0 (none), the `should` part behaves differently. If you add the default `match_all` things change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior changed in https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/7240 meaning starting with ES versions 1.3.3, 2.0 and 1.4.

In the meantime, **if** you can go over [this statement about `bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/bool-query.html#_controlling_precision):

> By default, none of the should clauses are required to match, with one exception: if there are no must clauses, then at least one should clause must match.

Then you can use this in your `must`:

```
        {
          "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "query": {"match_all": {}}
            },
            "boost": 0
          }
        }
```

To have an inoffensive (from scoring point of view) `must` statement.